# No of integral solutions in linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I am stuck upon a problem,in which I require to solve in 5 variables with one equation,linear. With a condition that the solutions must be non negative and integral as well as unequal. I couldn't think of any other way but to do this

[image: My approach]

I figured out that I can make cases but that seemed too tedious, is there any other way to do these questions. Pls Help. Thanks in advance.
Ps: I am in grade eleven so if you will be kind enough the pls don't make the soln too complex for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult problem and depends on the theory of partitions. What we want here is the number of distinct 5-partitions of $m$ - in other words, how many ways we can write $m$ as a sum of 5 distinct numbers, order of summation being not important. One can show that this is same as number of ways of writing $N=m - 15$ as a sum of at most 5 numbers (not necessarily distinct).  This is, if  $P(N,p)$ is the number of ways of writing $N$ as sum of $p$ positive integers, we need to compute $P(N, 1) + P(N,2) + P(N,3)+P(N,4)+P(N,5)$. There is no closed formula for $P(N,p)$ but one can compute by a recurrence relation
$$P(n,p) = P(n-p, p) + P(n-1, p-1) $$
See Barnard and Child, Higher Algebra for more details.

If you want the number of positive integral solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5 = m$ without the restriction $a_1 > a_2 > a_3 > a_4 > a_5$, then it is simple: this is the standard "starts and bars" problem with answer $\binom{m-1}{4}$